# Problem with MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql

Why does this query

```
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE id = ( SELECT id 
             FROM (SELECT * FROM test) temp 
             ORDER BY RAND() 
             LIMIT 1
           );
```

sometimes delete 1 row, sometimes 2 rows and sometimes nothing?

If I write it in this form:

```
SET @var = ( SELECT id 
             FROM (SELECT * FROM test) temp 
             ORDER BY RAND() 
             LIMIT 1
           ); 
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE id=@var;
```

then it work correctly - is problem in subquery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason the first query does not work consistently has to do with how MySQL processes subqueries. In fact, [***subqueries will experience rewrites and transformations***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transformation-in.html).

There are four(4) components explained here:

- Item_in_optimizer
- Item_in_subselect
- Item_ref
- Left_expression_Cache

From the examples posted, it would be impossible to allow an item_ref to become a self reference. In terms of your single DELETE query, the test table as a whole cannot fully self reference itself because some keys are available during transformation and some are not. Therefore, when a query performs a self-reference, a key (in this case id) can disappear in a transformation even though the actual self-referenced table has the key.

Mysql subqueries are only great for sub-SELECTs, even self-referencing a table multiple times. The same cannot be said for non-SELECT queries.

I hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 8):

I think that the reason why it doesn't work as expected is not how MySQL processes subqueries but how MySQL processes `UPDATE` statements. The statement:

```
DELETE 
FROM test 
WHERE id = 
      ( SELECT id 
        FROM 
            ( SELECT * 
              FROM test
            ) temp 
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 1
      )
```

will process the `WHERE` condition row by row. Meaning, for every row, it will run the subquery and test the result against `id`:

```
  ( SELECT id 
    FROM 
        ( SELECT * 
          FROM test
        ) temp 
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

So, it will occasionally match (and delete) 0, 1, 2 or even more rows!

---

You could rewrite it like this and the subquery will be processed once:

```
DELETE t
FROM 
      test t
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT id 
        FROM test  
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 1
      ) tmp
    ON tmp.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

From the first bullet on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html), `LIMIT` is not supported in mysql subqueries. I'm not sure why it doesn't throw an error for you, though.

Comment: `LIMIT` is not supported only for using `IN` _(<code> replaced with backticks ~ drachenstern)_

Comment: well...I learned something, which explains why it didn't toss an error!

Comment: @tomas.lang you can use ` (tick marks) surrounding the word, instead of <code> blocks.