# Dealing with temp tables when I have not control over db variables

Tags: mysql, query, innodb, temporary-tables

I have no control over things like `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size`, and so as our tables grow the time taken by queries requiring temp tables is growing geometrically.

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent MySQL from using temp tables for these queries? What would be the best approach in this situation:

Here is an example of the biggest offender:

```
SELECT `skills`.`id`
FROM (`jobs_skills`)
JOIN `jobs` ON (`jobs`.`id` = `jobs_skills`.`job_id`)
JOIN `skills` ON (`skills`.`id` = `jobs_skills`.`skill_id`)
WHERE `jobs`.`job_visibility_id` = 1
AND `jobs`.`active` = 1
AND `skills`.`valid` = 1
AND `jobs_skills`.`skill_id` IN (96,101,103,108,121,2610,99,119,2607,102,104,112,113,122,1032,1488,2608,109,126,1438,2310,2318,2622,118,1046,1387,2609,100,116,123,2611,2612,2616,2618,114,127,1562,1587,1608,2276,2615,125,1070,1071,1161,1658,2613,2614,2617,105,110,111,120,1394,1435)
GROUP BY `jobs_skills`.`job_id`
```

for which `copying to temp table` took 107 seconds, 99% of the total query time.

*despite fears of tl;dr syndrome, I am offering . . .*

**MORE DETAILS**

Here is the `EXPLAIN` statement for the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys        | key          | key_len | ref                              | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | jobs        | ref    | PRIMARY,active_index | active_index | 1       | const                            | 468958 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | jobs_skills | ref    | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY      | 4       | 557574_prod.jobs.id              |      1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | skills      | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY      | 4       | 557574_prod.jobs_skills.skill_id |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

and here are the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the relevant tables:

```
| jobs  | CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `address_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `proximity` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '15',
  `job_payrate_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `payrate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `job_start_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `duration` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Full-time, Part-time, Flexible',
  `posting_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `revision_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `expiration` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `team_size` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `job_type_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `job_shift_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `job_visibility_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `position_count` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `impressions` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `clicks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `employer_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `job_source_id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `job_password` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `active_index` (`active`),
  KEY `user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  KEY `address_id_index` (`address_id`),
  KEY `posting_date_index` USING BTREE (`posting_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=875013 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

-

```
| jobs_skills | CREATE TABLE `jobs_skills` (
  `job_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `skill_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `required` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`job_id`,`skill_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

-

```
| skills | CREATE TABLE `skills` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(35) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `valid` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `is_category` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `last_edited` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `impressions` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `clicks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `jobs` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2657 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Like I said, this is not the only query with this problem, so any general advice would be most helpful, though I will not decline any advice specific to this query.

Comment: This is actually a very good developer question that others may need to know about to circumvent limitations placed by hosting companies or senior DBAs. +1 on this question !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original subquery:

```
SELECT `skills`.`id`
FROM (`jobs_skills`)
JOIN `jobs` ON (`jobs`.`id` = `jobs_skills`.`job_id`)
JOIN `skills` ON (`skills`.`id` = `jobs_skills`.`skill_id`)
WHERE `jobs`.`job_visibility_id` = 1
AND `jobs`.`active` = 1
AND `skills`.`valid` = 1
AND `jobs_skills`.`skill_id` IN (96,101,103,108,121,2610,99,119,2607,102,104,112,113,122,1032,1488,2608,109,126,1438,2310,2318,2622,118,1046,1387,2609,100,116,123,2611,2612,2616,2618,114,127,1562,1587,1608,2276,2615,125,1070,1071,1161,1658,2613,2614,2617,105,110,111,120,1394,1435)
GROUP BY `jobs_skills`.`job_id`
```

You need to rafactor the query in such a way that you control and micromanage the temp tables being created and their sizes. Based solely on the JOIN, WHERE, and GROUP BY clauses, you need to implement the following changes:

jobs needs to be indexed on job_visibility_id,active,id

Needed Subquery

```
(SELECT id job_id FROM jobs WHERE job_visibility_id=1 AND active=1 ORDER BY id)
```

skills needs to be indexed on valid,id

Needed Subquery

```
(SELECT id skill_id FROM skills WHERE valid=1 ORDER BY id)
```

jobs_skills needs to be indexed on skill_id,job_id

Needed Subquery

```
(SELECT job_id FROM jobs_skills WHERE skill_id IN (96,101,103,108,121,2610,99,119,2607,102,104,112,113,122,1032,1488,2608,109,126,1438,2310,2318,2622,118,1046,1387,2609,100,116,123,2611,2612,2616,2618,114,127,1562,1587,1608,2276,2615,125,1070,1071,1161,1658,2613,2614,2617,105,110,111,120,1394,1435) ORDER BY skill_id,job_id)
```

SQL to create needed indexes

```
ALTER TABLE jobs ADD INDEX (job_visibility_id,active,id);
ALTER TABLE skills ADD INDEX (valid,id);
ALTER TABLE jobs_skills ADD INDEX (skill_id,job_id);
```

Now combine the Subqueries to form VOLTRON

```
SELECT skill_id
FROM (SELECT JS.*
FROM (SELECT skill_id,job_id FROM jobs_skills WHERE skill_id IN (96,101,103,108,121,2610,99,119,2607,102,104,112,113,122,1032,1488,2608,109,126,1438,2310,2318,2622,118,1046,1387,2609,100,116,123,2611,2612,2616,2618,114,127,1562,1587,1608,2276,2615,125,1070,1071,1161,1658,2613,2614,2617,105,110,111,120,1394,1435) ORDER BY skill_id,job_id) JS
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id job_id FROM jobs WHERE job_visibility_id=1 AND active=1 ORDER BY id) J
USING (job_id) INNER JOIN
(SELECT id skill_id FROM skills WHERE valid=1 ORDER BY id) S USING (skill_id)
) A
GROUP BY job_id;
```

Give it a Try !!!

BTW if the syntax is incorrect, I'll try to adjust it !!!

Comment: fantastic - I can see the underlying method of creating these indexes/subqueries & can apply it to the other problem-causing queries. Thanks!

Comment: @RolandMySQLDBA 'Now combine the Subqueries to form VOLTRON' lol... Thanks for the humor. Made my day...

Comment: I think if you had just forced the query to use the PRIMARY index for the jobs table, that would have helped as well, 

JOIN jobs FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY),

because as evident from the EXPLAIN output, the problem lies in the fact that MySQL is not choosing the optimal index when filtering rows from jobs table.

You can also use STRAIGHT_JOIN to force MySQL to follow your join plan,.

Comment: @ovais.tariq FORCE INDEX does not always help in most instances because the MySQL Query Optimizer has this filthy habit of optimizing away index hints due to making rows, suggestions, and even LIMIT clauses vanish into thin air (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384). The benefits of FORCE INDEX also get clobbered when JOIN clauses are done first and then WHERE clauses are applied to huge temp tables (which are never indexed).

Comment: @RolandMySQLDBA., yes joins are done first and in the order left to right., but indexes help the optimizer select the right table first,.
Suppose you have 3 tables, t1, t2 and t3,. they would be joined in order t3xt2xt1, if t3 can be filtered by the index to have the least number of rows,.
So by using force index you are actually making sure that the optimizer is joining left to right in an optimized way,.

Comment: @RolandMySQLDBA,., there is yet another thing that I forgot to mention, optimizer depends a lot on the underlying table engine, because its the underlying table engine that reports the index statistics that are then used by the optimizer to create a query plan,.

and InnoDB is different in that the statistics that are generated are not persistent,. so for suppose there are two indexes that could fulfill a query condition, then innodb would have to do index dives for both the indexes to tell the optimizer which one is better, in such cases FORCE INDEX would prevent those index dives,.

Comment: @tariq The Query Optimizer will sometimes optimize the FORCE INDEX away if the cardinality of the index columns are lopsided. In principle using FORCE INDEX is just straight up bad practice due to very bad data organization. Think about it: Should you ever have to coerce mysql to perform a FORCE INEX on a Primary Key? This is a strong indication that either the primary key choice was just bad or that mysql designed FORCE INDEX horrifically.