# MySQL / InnoDB: Does daily optimization improve performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, optimization

Would performing daily optimizations of tables increase performance for MySQL and InnoDB? I have never did this before, but I have seen this module for Drupal http://drupal.org/project/db_maintenance, and it looks promising.

PS: As I learned, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` liberates overhead. However, I double checked the overhead column in mysql and it is all empty for my innodb tables ... So, I guess this may not be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## MyISAM

Doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable;` performs two basic operations

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=MyISAM;
ANALYZE TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

This definitely cleans up table fragmentation and computes fresh statistics for indexes

## InnoDB

Doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable;` performs two basic operations

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
ANALYZE TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

While this eliminates fragmentation, `ANAYLZE TABLE` is complete useless for InnoDB. I wrote about this a long time ago:

- `Jun 21, 2011` : [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402)
- `Oct 16, 2011` : [Suddenly have to rebuild indexes to prevent site from going down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/suddenly-have-to-rebuild-indexes-to-prevent-site-from-going-down/6856#6856)

If your data growth rate is very small (or in other words, your dataset stays basically the same size for months at a time), then defragmenting tables would just be overkill. You should probably focus on tuning InnoDB's other aspects (See my `Aug 04, 2011` post: [Optimizing InnoDB default settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/optimizing-innodb-default-settings/4325#4325))

I also have posts in the Drupal StackExchange on opimizing MySQL

- `Jun 07, 2011` : [How do I convert a database from MyISAM to InnoDB?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/4794/989)
- `Apr 15, 2011` : [What would be the optimal MySQL configuration for a Drupal 7 site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2367/989)

Answer (score 1):

For it worth :
I"ve ran optimize table on the main tables of a database who works under heavy load. The main tables have been under great load of inserts/updates/deletes.
The optimize reduced the table sizes by 90% and improved the system performance by more than twice !