# What is the difference between OPTIMIZE TABLE and ANALYZE TABLE table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

What is the difference between `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and `ANALYZE TABLE` table in MySQL? I have read the online documentation but not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 34):

To expand on [**@MitchWheat's answer**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35522/877) (+1 for directly answering first):

[**ANALYZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html) examines key distribution and stores them in [**INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/statistics-table.html).

[**OPTIMIZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) performs [**ANALYZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html) after doing some table compression. The equivalent of `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable;` if the table was MyISAM is this:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=MyISAM;
ANALYZE TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

## MyISAM

For the MyISAM table mydb.mytable in datadir `/var/lib/mysql`, you have the following files:

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.MYD` (data)
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.MYI` (indexes)

`OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable` would shrink the `.MYD` and `.MYI` files for the table.

This is not the same for InnoDB. Here is how it is different:

## InnoDB ([innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled)

Each table's data and indexes are stored in an external tablespace file. For `datadir` is `/var/lib/mysql`  and the table `mydb.mytable`, it would be stored as follows:

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd`

When `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable` is executed, `mytable.ibd` gets shrunk.

## InnoDB ([innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled)

Only `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm` would exist. All the data and index pages for the table `mydb.mytable` are stored in the system tablespace file `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`.

When `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable` is executed, the data and index pages are written contiguously in ibdata1. Unfortunately, this make ibdata1 grow in leaps and bounds.

See the [Pictorial Representation from Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

[image: InnoDB Plumbing]

## UPDATE 2013-02-26 22:33 EST

You comment was

> I think, optimize table for innodb is not supported. I got a message, index will be recreated. How does it work?

I tried this out

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.5.29 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> create table dat (a int, primary key (a));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into dat values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> analyze table dat;
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
| Table    | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
| test.dat | analyze | status   | OK       |
+----------+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> optimize table dat;
+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test.dat | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| test.dat | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.14 sec)

mysql>
```

You are correct. You cannot run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` as a single operation. What InnoDB does instead is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
ANALYZE TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

You could also just run these steps yourself.

However, in all honesty, you should not have to run `ANALYZE TABLE` against an InnoDB table because each time a query is executed, the InnoDB Storage Engine performs an estimation on table cardinality based on passing through pages in the indexes. If there are a high number of `INSERTs`, `UPDATEs`, and `DELETEs`, then you will need to `ANALYZE TABLE`. When there is a high number of `DELETEs`, then `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;` is needed to shrink the table.

I actually wrote posts about the futility of `ANALYZE TABLE` on InnoDB in certain instances:

- `Oct 16, 2011` : [Suddenly have to rebuild indexes to prevent site from going down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/suddenly-have-to-rebuild-indexes-to-prevent-site-from-going-down/6856#6856)
- `Jun 21, 2011` : [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402)

Comment: I think, optimize table for innodb is not supported. I got a  message, index will be recreated. How does it work?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I'm not sure what mean when you say, "you cannot run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`."  When you `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for an InnoDB table, MySQL is performing the `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB` and `ANALYZE TABLE ...` operations for you when it says "doing recreate + analyze table instead."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot As shown in my answer, I ran `OPTIMIZE TABLE dat;` in MySQL 5.5.29 and it complained immediately, `Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead`. That's why I recommend `ALTER TABLE dat ENGINE=InnoDB; ANALYZE TABLE dat;`.

Comment: Right, but I would assert that it happened immediately for you because the table you tested against was very small.  When you `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on InnoDB, the server actually does in fact execute `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB` and `ANALYZE TABLE` behind the scenes before returning that response... so you can indeed run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on InnoDB, and achieve the intended effect.

Answer (score 22):

Depends on your version of MySQL and storage engine but in general:

**OPTIMIZE TABLE**
Analyzes table, stores the key distribution for a table, reclaims the unused space and defragments the data file.

**ANALYZE TABLE**
Only analyzes table and stores the key distribution.