# Check (health) status of MySQL schema table

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, mysql-workbench

I have a large MySQL database which has around 1,500 tables and the file of the database is around 30GB. I would like to suggest me some ways to monitor the health of my database in overall and how i can check the health status of mysql schema table.

How can I monitor the health of my database in overall? I use mysql workbence, but since i am new to this, i don't know what to check!

Comment: What do you consider "health"?  Outage?  Performance?  Hackers?

Comment: @leonidas  Please view my profile, Network profile for contact info including my website where you will find 'Utility Scripts+' that has a FREE script to findfragtables.sql you may download and run.  Post the results of page 1 and we will have some info to work with related to health of the tables listed on page 1.

Answer (score 7):

To monitor your database's health in all tables of all databases and automatically repair any corruption:

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases --auto-repair
```

Or, you can also optimize all tables (but be aware of performance considerations):

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases --auto-repair --optimize
```

If you want to verify a single table instead, run this command replacing `mydb` and `mytable`:

```
mysql
CHECK TABLE mydb.mytable FAST QUICK;
```

Read more:

- [What is the difference between OPTIMIZE TABLE and ANALYZE TABLE table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35520/what-is-the-difference-between-optimize-table-and-analyze-table-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! One last question: When i run these commands, the read/write/insert on the database should be stopped or i can run these commands on a working database?

Comment: This process increases I/O operations, would be safe to run out of working time for the first time and watch resource usage using  sar (sysstat) in another session. Or schedule a crontab job to run. Then depending on resource usage you could run on a work database.

Comment: Hey there, the problem is that I can't stop the database at all, because my working time is 24/7!! 

Any idea?

Comment: Optimize is quite invasive and generally unnecessary, especially for InnoDB.

Comment: For your 24x7 scenario avoid to use the optimize and cancel the check operation if it's necessary. You can check tables separatelly and after be sure that your db performance wasn't affected you can check per databases. I'll update the answer with table options.