# Occasionally Need to OPTIMIZE TABLE after table creation -- MariaDB 10.6.11

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, optimization, mariadb-10.6

I transfer tables from one server to another by running the `CREATE TABLE` statement without any indexes. Then I batch insert all of the data into the table. Then I run an `ALTER TABLE` to add the indexes.

Occasionally when I do this I notice queries will run slowly so I run an `EXPLAIN` and the query is not using the correct index or not using an index at all. Then I run an `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, and that seems to resolve the issue.

So I have two questions :

1. Is there an automated way I can know when I need to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on a table that has become 'unoptimized'?
2. More importantly, what am I doing that is causing this issue?

I have only noticed this issue on MariaDB 10.6.11 running on Ubuntu 22.04. I have never had this issue in the past on older versions of Ubuntu/MariaDB.

This has happened previously to tables that are well over 100GB, and I just assumed it had something to do with too many updates, inserts, deletes. However, it happened this morning on a table that is only 250MB immediately after a fresh `CREATE`, `INSERT`, `ALTER`.

Comment: Which `ENGINE`?

Comment: @Rick James -- InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

You can update the index statistics without doing OPTIMIZE TABLE

When you run

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE mytable;
```

This is what OPTIMIZE TABLE does under the hood for InnoDB

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
ANALYZE TABLE mytable;
```

In details

- The first line copies the table to a temp table, switching temp table for the original table.
- The second line reads the index info and compiles the index statistics

You can skip the first line and just run

```
ANALYZE TABLE mytable;
```

I discussed this before in my post from `Feb 27, 2013`: [What is the difference between OPTIMIZE TABLE and ANALYZE TABLE table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35520/what-is-the-difference-between-optimize-table-and-analyze-table-table-in-mysql/35523#35523)

Comment: It's worth reassuring the user that ANALYZE TABLE does not lock the table, does not take a long time regardless of table size, and it's totally safe to run this anytime. It's a read-only task.