# Is ANALYZE useful immediately after creating an InnoDB index?

Tags: mysql, innodb, index

Let's create a new index on an existing table:

```
CREATE INDEX `IDX_some_index`
    ON `some_table` (`a_column`, `another_column`);
```

Is this useful?

```
ANALYZE TABLE `some_table`;
```

Can anyone point to some documentation clarifying whether the `CREATE INDEX` process analyze the target table or not?

Answer (score 3):

[CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) does not issue [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html).

When it comes to InnoDB, running [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) is kind of useless. Why ?

I wrote this post [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402) 2.5 years ago.

In it, I explained that [InnoDB can overwrite statistics by means of just running queries](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/). The Query Optimizer will do depth searches in BTREE indexes and take guesses at the cardinality of index column combinations. In a relatively short time, I would say that index stats can get stale. This applies to older versions of MySQL 5.

From the [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) Documentation for MySQL 5.6, [InnoDB's stats are persistent by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance.html#innodb-persistent-stats). Thus, running [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) on InnoDB tables for MySQL 5.6 actually means statistics are computed and will only deteriorate via heavy INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs.

As for you question, I say : [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) does not issue [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) automatically.

Comment: I'm familiar with a few use cases where it is clearly beneficial to run an `ANALYZE TABLE` once or twice per day, in that without it the query execution plans go terribly wrong (as in "why would it ever think this might be a good plan?"). With it, they are correct.