# Convert Oracle query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I've just tried to convert this update command, which is Oracle sql, to MySQL with SQLWays and it failed with the following error:

> You can't specify target table 'animal_table' for update in FROM clause

source command (Oracle):

```
UPDATE animal_table
     SET (animal_info1, 
          animal_info2, 
          animal_info3) = (SELECT animal_nbr, animal_amount, '00'
                           FROM animal_table t2
                           WHERE t2.category_id = animal_table.category_id
                             AND t2.sumary_id = animal_table.summary_id
                             AND t2.animal_type = 'special'
                          )
  WHERE animal_type = 'cats'
    AND category_id = 'foo';
```

suggested target command (MySQL):

```
UPDATE animal_table
SET 
    animal_info1 = (SELECT animal_nbr FROM animal_table t2 
                    WHERE t2.category_id = animal_table.category_id
                    AND t2.sumary_id = animal_table.summary_id
                    AND t2.animal_type = 'special'),
    animal_info2 = (SELECT animal_amount FROM animal_table t2 
                    WHERE t2.category_id = animal_table.category_id
                    AND t2.sumary_id = animal_table.summary_id
                    AND t2.animal_type = 'special'),
    animal_info3 = (SELECT '00' FROM animal_table t2 
                    WHERE t2.category_id = animal_table.category_id
                    AND t2.sumary_id = animal_table.summary_id
                    AND t2.animal_type = 'special')
    WHERE animal_type = 'cats'
    AND category_id = 'foo';
```

can anyone help me out here?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/45498#45498) SO answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an UPDATE JOIN of the table against itself

```
UPDATE
    animal_table A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        category_id,summary_id,
        animal_nbr,animal_amount,'00' info3
    FROM animal_table
    WHERE animal_type = 'special'
) B USING (category_id,summary_id)
SET
    A.animal_info1 = B.animal_nbr,
    A.animal_info2 = B.animal_amount,
    A.animal_info3 = B.info3
WHERE
    A.animal_type = 'cats' AND
    A.category_id = 'foo';
```

Make sure that animal_table has a compound index on category_id and summary_id. If you do not have such an index, please run this:

```
ALTER TABLE animal_table ADD INDEX (category_id,summary_id);
```

**UPDATE 2011-09-27 13:10 EDT**

I just noticed that categrory_id 'foo' limits the dataset. Here is an updated refactoring of my answer ( I moved category_id = foo into the subquery )

```
UPDATE
    animal_table A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        category_id,summary_id,
        animal_nbr,animal_amount,'00' info3
    FROM animal_table
    WHERE animal_type = 'special'
    AND category_id = 'foo'
) B USING (category_id,summary_id)
SET
    A.animal_info1 = B.animal_nbr,
    A.animal_info2 = B.animal_amount,
    A.animal_info3 = B.info3
WHERE
    A.animal_type = 'cats';
```

I also recommend adding this additional index to accommodate the subquery

```
ALTER TABLE animal_table ADD INDEX (animal_type,category_id);
```

Comment: Nice. implicit temporary table > explicit temp table on my end. +1

Comment: thanks Rolando, this also helped me to understand the basics of INNER JOINs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in MySQL, you cannot update a table that you've listed in a subquery. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) (at the end):

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

You can nest the subqueries like so (untested):

```
UPDATE animal_table
SET 
animal_info1 = (SELECT animal_nbr FROM (SELECT animal_nbr FROM animal_table t2 
                WHERE t2.category_id = animal_table.category_id
                AND t2.sumary_id = animal_table.summary_id
                AND t2.animal_type = 'special') as X),
animal_info2 = (SELECT animal_amount FROM (SELECT animal_amount FROM animal_table t2 
                WHERE t2.category_id = animal_table.category_id
                AND t2.sumary_id = animal_table.summary_id
                AND t2.animal_type = 'special') AS Y),
animal_info3 = (SELECT '00' FROM (SELECT '00' FROM animal_table t2 
                WHERE t2.category_id = animal_table.category_id
                AND t2.sumary_id = animal_table.summary_id
                AND t2.animal_type = 'special')AS Z)
WHERE animal_type = 'cats'
AND category_id = 'foo';
```

But I think [Rolando's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/convert-oracle-query-to-mysql/6229#6229) is cleaner, since it doesn't duplicate the subqueries.

Comment: +1 for explaining why the original query does not work due to subquery headaches.

Comment: Isn't the suggested target command containing temporary tables in subquery? If not, can you please add that example command please?

Comment: @DTest - Remember we dealt with subquery issues in a past question ? http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1371/877

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this, but please test it before running on some sample data:

```
UPDATE animal_table t1 inner join animal_table t2
ON t2.category_id = t1.category_id 
AND t2.sumary_id = t1.summary_id 
AND t2.animal_type = 'special'
SET t1.animal_info1 = t2.animal_nbr, 
t1.animal_info2 = t2.animal_amount, 
t1.animal_info3 = '00'
where t1.animal_type = 'cats'
and t1.category_id = 'foo';
```

Comment: Your query matches the one in my answer. Mine is just refactored. Your answer would still work. +1 !!!

Comment: Actually, I would like the original poster to check if it does. Joins do not always equal the data from sub queries.

Comment: I would still use Rolandos version, since his example is well formatted and easy to scale (multiple JOINs)

Comment: if you say so :)