# MySQL hang in load data infile command

Tags: mysql, locking

From the link: [LOAD DATA (400k rows) INFILE takes about 7 minutes, cannot kill the "logging slow query" process?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12304/load-data-400k-rows-infile-takes-about-7-minutes-cannot-kill-the-logging-slo)

I had changed the command order (unlock before commit + replace some queries to slave), and the db server runs pretty well . But I want to ask more question around why my db server hangs?

I'm not sure of the main reason that @RolandoMySQLDBA mention that lets the db server hang. You can test my command:
Session1: (lock table and don't throw unlock tables command).

```
#session 1
Lock table  **v3_zone_date** WRITE;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0; 
LOAD DATA INFILE '/data10/select_into.outfile/v3_zone_date.out' INTO TABLE v3_zone_date 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ','; 
COMMIT;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;#ok

#Session2: 
SELECT * FROM **v3_cam_date** LIMIT 1; #ok
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0; 
LOAD DATA INFILE '/data10/select_into.outfile/v3_cam_date.out' INTO TABLE v3_cam_date     
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ','; 
COMMIT;  
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;#ok
```

So, if I tried to get x lock from table v3_domain_date in session1, and then running query to other tables in session 2, everything Ok (not lock or hang out db). Of course, I can't query to the v3_domain_date (be cause the table was locked with x lock).

can any one explain for me?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Please look carfully at session 1.

```
Lock table v3_zone_date WRITE; 
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;  
LOAD DATA INFILE '/data10/select_into.outfile/v3_zone_date.out' INTO TABLE v3_zone_date  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',';  
COMMIT; 
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
```

should be

```
Lock table v3_zone_date WRITE; 
LOAD DATA INFILE '/data10/select_into.outfile/v3_zone_date.out' INTO TABLE v3_zone_date  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',';  
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

No need to have these lines

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
COMMIT; 
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
```

because [MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide, Chapter 29, Page 418 Bulletpoint #1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127) says

> UNLOCK TABLES implicitly commits only if you have explicitly locked
>   tables with LOCK TABLES. SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1 implicitly commits only
>   if autocommit mode wasn't already enabled.

LOCK TABLES will hold up any transaction-based row locks that are trying to be acquired.

Since the tables are locked independently, you must just need to increase the size of your InnoDB Buffer Pool ([**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)) to make more room for row locks across all InnoDB tables.