# Select rows where value of second column is not present in first column

Tags: mysql, join

I have this table structure:

```
 id1 id2
 1   2 
 1   3
 1   4
 2   1
 2   5
```

I need to build a query to select `id2` where `id1` is not in `id2`. For example if `id1 = 1` then only `id2=3` and `id2=4`.
I tried this one:

```
SET @a=1;
SELECT DISTINCT x.id2 
 FROM tt x, tt y 
 WHERE x.id1=@a AND x.id1 != y.id2;
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @a=1;
SELECT x.id2
FROM (SELECT * FROM tt WHERE id1=@a) x LEFT JOIN tt y
ON x.id2 = y.id1
WHERE y.id1 IS NULL;
```

I tried it against my query and it works

```
mysql> select * from tt;
+------+------+
| id1  | id2  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    5 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @a=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT x.id2
    -> FROM (SELECT * FROM tt WHERE id1=@a) x LEFT JOIN tt y
    -> ON x.id2 = y.id1
    -> WHERE y.id1 IS NULL;
+------+
| id2  |
+------+
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### **UPDATE 2012-04-18 11:58 EDT**

You can take the entire query and

- make it a subquery
- LEFT JOIN the subquery to the users, groups, and profiles tables

maybe something like this

```
SET @a=1;
SELECT u.*,g.*,p.* FROM
(
    SELECT x.id2 user_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM tt WHERE id1=@a) x LEFT JOIN tt y
    ON x.id2 = y.id1
    WHERE y.id1 IS NULL
) keys
LEFT JOIN users u USING (user_id)
LEFT JOIN groups g USING (user_id)
LEFT JOIN profiles p USING (user_id)
;
```

Comment: +1 The sub-select might speed things up a bit (compared to the raw LEFT JOIN version). Or is the planner smart enough to avoid unnecessary JOIN operations all by himself?

Comment: @Erwin Subselects are good as long as MySQL uses indexes and does not make rows disappear while optimizing : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1384/877

Comment: @Erwin For SELECT queries, the MySQL Query Optimizer is smart enough to avoid unnecessary JOIN operations. I still prefer refactoring queries if the explain plan isn't messier after the refactor.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting link. A bit disturbing, but good to know. And thanks for the update on the query optimizer!

Answer (score 9):

For the **simple case** of a single given `id1`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.id2   -- DISTINCT only needed if there are dupes
FROM   tbl x
WHERE  x.id1 =  @a
AND    x.id2 <> @a;
```

**Generally**, there are basically **four techniques** to do what you are after. Both columns could just as well be in different tables, almost the same problem.

#### `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.id2 
FROM   tbl x
WHERE  <some condition>
AND    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM tbl y
    WHERE  <some condition>
    AND    y.id1 = x.id2
    );
```

#### `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.id2 
FROM   tbl x
LEFT   JOIN tbl y ON y.id1 = x.id2
                 AND <some condition for y>
WHERE  <some condition for x>
AND    y.id1 IS NULL
```

#### `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id2
FROM   tbl
WHERE  <some condition>

EXCEPT ALL            -- ALL to make it faster - no dupes left after DISTINCT
SELECT tbl.id1
FROM   tbl
WHERE  <some condition>
```

#### `NOT IN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.id2 
FROM   tbl x
WHERE  <some condition>
AND    x.id2 NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id1
    FROM   tbl y
    WHERE  <some condition>
    );
```

You'll have to test which one is fastest for you. Benchmarks disagree. It depends on data distribution and other details. `NOT IN` rarely wins. It's mostly one of the first two.

As @ypercube commented: if `(id1, id2)` is unique, the `DISTINCT` clause is not needed - except the one in the `NOT IN` sub-query, which is meant to help performance.

Related answer with more details for PostgreSQL on SO:

- [**Select rows which are not present in other table**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Comment: I tried it and it works. +1 for getting it first !!!

Comment: Second one works !!!

Comment: If `(id1, id2)` combination is unique, then we can skip the `DISTINCT`

Comment: @ypercube: indeed we can (except for the one in the NOT IN sub-select). But that condition has not been declared in the question.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` at the `NOT IN` subselect is not needed anyway (except for performance).

Comment: @ypercube: And for performance it is meant.

Comment: An observation. If `(id1, id2)` combination is not unique, then there are 2 more variations. Changing versions 1 (or 3) by removing the `DISTINCT`, adding `GROUP BY x.id2` and moving the `NOT EXISTS` (or `NOT IN`) condition to `HAVING` clause. This may produce different execution plans.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay but I was very busy. Now I have another problem related to the same question: I need to get the rows where id1 and id2 are in both sides meaning this: id1=1, id2=2, id1=2, id2=1 think in a switch for rows, can any help me with this one? Any way thanks to every who takes some minutes in try to help me with my original problem.

Comment: @ReynierPM: Please clarify something for us - **in your question**: Is `(id1, id2)` unique? I suspect you don't need `DISTINCT`at all. You should edit your question or write a new one with major information. Don't put it all in comments. You can always drop a line of comment to notify me.

Comment: Ok, my bad I don't know how to notify you but anyway I open a new post here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/select-for-values-in-a-table hope you can help me on this too and many thanks

Comment: @ReynierPM: No problem. This is a QA-site after all. [Here is how notifying works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).