# SELECT for values in a table

Tags: mysql, query

I have this table structure:

```
id1   id2
 1     2
 1     3
 2     1
 2     4
```

id1 and id2 are not unique as you can see in the values. I need to retrieve those values that exists in the two columns meaning id1=1,2 id2=2,1. Any help?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Is the combination of `id1` and `id2` unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT x.id1, x.id2 
FROM   tbl x
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl y
    WHERE  (y.id1, y.id2) = (x.id2, x.id1)
    );
```

Assuming that the **combination** of `(id1, id2)` is unique, so no `DISTINCT`. This would still allow `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` to coexist (and both will be returned), but no two rows with `(1,2)`.

Also assuming `id1 != id2` for every row (deriving from your test data and question). A unique entry `(1,1)` without doppelganger would be returned by this query. If my first assumption is true, you can exclude `id1 = id2` right away. Else, you'd need something like [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) to identify duplicates ...

A [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) would greatly speed up such a query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_id1_id2_idx ON tbl (id1, id2);
```

Use it without `UNIQUE` keyword, should `(id1, id2)` not be unique after all.

---

Or, you can use those other techniques discussed under [your prequel question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16651/3684), accordingly modified.

Comment: Brandstetter, yes they are unique because only one 1,2 is allowed altough my bad because I completely forgot to make this two fields unique when build the DB. I'll test the queries tomorrow at office because I can't from home anyway this is a table for relation between users where id1 (user who start the relation) invites id2(user who receives the invitation). Then if id1=1 then id2 can't be 1 because a user can't invite himself. So id1=1, id2=2 can exists. So if id2 accept the invitation a new row will be created with values id1=2, id2=1 so I can know that user id=2 accepts.

Comment: Many thanks @Erwin this works perfectly, you save my day

Comment: Hi @erwin-brandstetter I try with UNIQUE fields as you suggested before but now I'm trying to insert another couple of id1,id2 and I can't. See the results below: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'id1'

INSERT INTO `default_relations_users` (`id1`, `id2`) VALUES ('2', '4')

Comment: @ReynierPM: The error message suggests that you created a unique constraint on just `id1`, but I suggested a unique constraint on `(id1, id2)`. Follow the link in my answer for details about multicolumn indexes.

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter thaks that was the problem I didn't create the INDEX right now it works

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter I've another question related to this same table. I need to build a query for get the id2 that aren't in id1 but didn't know how to do this. For example for id=1 the query should return just 3 and not 2 because id1=2 exists