# How to DELETE duplicate entries on a field

Tags: mysql, query

I have a huge table that has 1,990,546 users with numerous data.  Sometimes I get email lists and dump them into this table also.

I want to delete users with duplicate email addresses.  However, I want to keep users `WHERE chips > 0`.

This query ran for over an hour before I terminated it:

```
SELECT id, email  
FROM users 
WHERE id IN 
    ( 
        SELECT a.id 
        FROM users a, users b     
        WHERE (a.email = b.email) 
        AND (a.chips > 0)  
    )
LIMIT 100;
```

Is there a faster or better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a temp table

```
#
# Collect All IDs Your Intend to Keep
#
CREATE TABLE KeepIDList ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT id FROM users;
CREATE TABLE KeepIDList ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT id FROM users;
INSERT INTO KeepIDList (id) SELECT min_id FROM
(SELECT email,MIN(id) min_id FROM users GROUP BY email) A;
ALTER TABLE KeepIDList ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
#
# Collect All IDs Your Intend to Delete
#
CREATE TABLE ZapIDList ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT id FROM users;
INSERT INTO ZapIDList (id)
SELECT A.id FROM users A LEFT JOIN KeepIDList B WHERE B.id IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE KeepIDList ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
#
# From Collected Keys to Delete, Remove Keys Whose chips > 0
#
DELETE B.* FROM users A INNER JOIN ZapIDList B WHERE A.chips > 0;
#
# From Collected Keys Left to Delete, Perform DELETE JOIN
#
DELETE A.* FROM users A INNER JOIN ZapIDList B;
#
# Drop Temp Tables
#
DROP TABLE KeepIDList;
DROP TABLE ZapIDList;
```

I have a very good reason for using temp tables as opposed to doing a Direct DELETE JOIN of a table against itself: Performing a DELETE using a subquery that references the same table experiencing the DELETE tends to make keys disappear intermittently as the query is being optimized. I wrote about this back on Feb 22, 2011 : [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384)

CAVEAT

**Please test this out with a smaller dataset to make sure my answer indeed performs what you asked. Make sure you make s backup of the `users` table. To coin a phrase from 1960's  Mission Impossible: [Should any of your data be caught or killed, I will disavow any knowledge of your actions (Start From 1:50 of the YouTube Video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZF79TudRiM).**

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
DELETE t1
FROM users AS t1 
JOIN 
(
   SELECT id
   FROM users
   WHERE chips <= 0
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
) AS t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

I hope this helps you.