# Removing duplicate entries for each hour

Tags: postgresql

I recently asked the same question about MySQL, which has since been migrated to Postgres.
[Old question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28129/5732).

To sum it up:

I have a table with an id (**type UUID**), a timestamp, and some text (row3). How do I retain only one entry per hour for each distinct value of row3?

What I tried is this:

```
INSERT INTO log_table
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(id) id
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY row3, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "time"), id
);
TRUNCATE table1;
```

But this, unfortunately, inserts every row from table1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Generic case

Say you want to retain the values belonging the `max(id)` for every hour and for every distinct `row3` value (but see the UUID section below).  The IDs of these you get with a query like

```
SELECT max(id)
FROM table1
GROUP BY row3, EXTRACT(hour FROM "time")
;
```

(This will omit the date from your data, which is what you may want—or not.  In the latter case you may want to use `date_trunc('hour', "time")` instead.)

Then you can use the above query to populate a table just as you did in your question, or delete everything else from `table1` like

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN (
    [the query above comes here]
)
;
```

### UUID

There is no `max()` for UUID.  Therefore another solution is needed in your case, like this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_value(id) OVER w
FROM table1
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY row3, EXTRACT(hour FROM "time")
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
;
```

This one applies a window function, and the grouping is achieved by the `PARTITION BY` clause and `DISTINCT`.

(Acknowledgment: thanks for the idea for AndriyM!)