# Is there any way to trace optimizer's work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Just like the MEMO structure in SQL Server which is kind of a "paper trail" of steps the optimizer takes in optimizing the query. Is there anything in MySQL through which I can get the information like, which plans the optimizer considers, the cost of each plan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recent 5.6 version has added this feature.

See: [MySQL Internals Manual ::chapter **9. Tracing the Optimizer**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html)

Typical Usage:

```
# Turn tracing on (it's off by default):
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=on";

SELECT ...; # your query here

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OPTIMIZER_TRACE;

# possibly more queries...

# When done with tracing, disable it:
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=off";
```

You can see it in action in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8096/1). Not sure how the output can be beautified.

Comment: +1 for using new information_schema table for MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can immediately mention is to simply run EXPLAIN on a query.

There is a graphical way to do this

- [**pt-visual-explain**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-visual-explain.html)
- [**mk-visual-explain**](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-visual-explain.html) ([*Source Code*](https://code.google.com/p/maatkit/source/browse/trunk/mk-visual-explain/mk-visual-explain?r=4575))

As for steps to optimizing a query, a parse tree is created. Rather than explaining the parser here, please read my post from Mar 11, 2013 ([*Is there an execution difference between a JOIN condition and a WHERE condition?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36409/877)) on what the parser does.