# Performance: MySQL id = vs id IN (multiple values)

Tags: mysql, performance

I've found posts of **= vs IN** for **single value** ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37828398/134824) and [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-in-42-and-id-42-in-mysql)), but I'm asking actually for **multiple values**. Which is likely to perform better:

```
# Query 1:
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 50 OR id = 51 OR id = 52

# Query 2:
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN (50, 51, 52)

# Query 3:
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id >= 50 AND id <= 52
```

Note: id is primary and indexed, obviously.

Comment: These are also equivalent with `WHERE id BETWEEN 50 AND 52`

Comment: `Q1` and `Q2` are eqs. `Q3` and `Q by Lennart` are eqs. But this pairs of queries  are NOT equivalent formally (for example, nothing in the text above prevent `id` to be floating-point number).

Comment: @Lennart I'm asking about performance, would one perform better than others if I used many multiple ids?

Comment: I don't _think_ `IN` turns into `OR`, nor vice versa:  See [_here_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613647/1766831)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance).

I've done some benchmark on all 3 queries on a table with 500,000 records with index on `id`. I fetched 10,000 rows. I did the same tests on MyISAM and Innodb, all same results. I made sure that for each query I used different set of numbers, so the query is not cached by MySQL. I did the tests multiple times, and I got similar numbers every time.

Benchmark results (average):

- Query 1, fetch by **= OR =**: 3.700 seconds
- Query 2, fetch by **IN**: 0.037 seconds
- Query 3, fetch by **>= && <=**: 0.005 seconds
- Query 4, fetch by **between**: same as **>= && <=**

Comment: Was your Query-1 with `OR`?  Or separate `SELECTs`?  Was the cache warm?

Comment: @RickJames Query1 with OR. I'm not sure how to disable cache, but I used different ids set for each test.

Comment: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` is a handy way to avoid the Query Cache when timing.  But that is not what I meant to ask...  Right after a restart, data is sitting only on disk.  The first query will be slow due to I/O.  To avoid this false timing, run the select twice and take the second timing.  (A third run _should_ be the same speed as the second.)

Comment: What version were these tests performed in?