# Can someone explain why left joining two views in mysql is so slow?

Tags: mysql, join, view

Here is a question I asked yesterday - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180727/left-joining-two-views-is-slow.

I got a good answer that helped me but I don't understand why the LEFT JOIN is so much slower than the lookup.  The LEFT JOIN was 16 seconds - and I am pretty sure my tables are at least 90% optimized - and when doing the lookup it is just .14 seconds.   When I LEFT JOIN tables it is not this slow so why views?

Comment: How are the tables beneath the views indexed?  Do the columns you are LEFT JOINing with have useful indexes for this join?

Comment: @RLF - There are two fields uid and trid that are used for all the joins and both fields are indexed on all of their tables.  I can make tables out of the views and LEFT JOIN is like 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Documentation on Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/views.html)

> Views (including updatable views) are available in MySQL Server 5.6. Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set. A view acts as a virtual table.

The first thing that must be realized about a view is that it produces a result set. The result set emerging from query invoked from the view is a virtual table because it is created on-demand. There is no DDL you can summon afterwards to immediately index the result set. For all intents and purposes, the result set is a table without any indexes. In effect, the LEFT JOIN you were executing is basically a Cartesian product with some filtering.

To give you a more granular look at the JOIN of two views, I will refer to a post I made last year explaining the internal mechanisms MySQL uses to evaluate JOINs and WHEREs ([Is there an execution difference between a JOIN condition and a WHERE condition?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36391/is-there-an-execution-difference-between-a-join-condition-and-a-where-condition/36409#36409)). I will show you the mechanism as published in [**Understanding MySQL Internals**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577) (Page 172):

- Determine which keys can be used to retrieve the records from tables, and choose the best one for each table.
- For each table, decide whether a table scan is better that reading on a key. If there are  a lot of records that match the key value, the advantages of the key are reduced and the table scan becomes faster.
- Determine the order in which tables should be joined when more than one table is present in the query.
- Rewrite the WHERE clauses to eliminate dead code, reducing the unnecessary computations and changing the constraints wherever possible to the open the way for using keys.
- Eliminate unused tables from the join.
- Determine whether keys can be used for `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`.
- Attempt to simplify subqueries, as well as determine to what extent their results can be cached.
- Merge views (expand the view reference as a macro)

OK, it seems like indexes should be used. However, look closer. If you substitute word `View` for `Table`, look what happens to the mechanism's execution:

#### MECHANISM MODIFIED

- Determine which keys can be used to retrieve the records from **`views`**, and choose the best one for each **`view`**.
- For each **`view`**, decide whether a **`view`** scan is better that reading on a key. If there are  a lot of records that match the key value, the advantages of the key are reduced and the **`view`** scan becomes faster.
- Determine the order in which **`views`** should be joined when more than one **`views`** is present in the query.
- Rewrite the WHERE clauses to eliminate dead code, reducing the unnecessary computations and changing the constraints wherever possible to the open the way for using keys.
- Eliminate unused **`views`** from the join.
- Determine whether keys can be used for `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`.
- Attempt to simplify subqueries, as well as determine to what extent their results can be cached.
- Merge views (expand the view reference as a macro)

Every table (view) has no index. Thus, working with virtual tables, temp tables, or tables with no indexes really becomes indistinct when doing a JOIN. The keys used are just for JOIN operations, not so much for looking things up faster.

Think of [your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180727/left-joining-two-views-is-slow) as picking up two phone books, the 2014 Yellow Pages and the 2013 Yellow Pages. Each Yellow Pages book contains the White Pages for Residential Phone Numbers.

- In late 2012, a database table was used to generate the 2013 Yellow Pages.
- During 2013

  - People changed phone numbers
  - People received new phone numbers
  - People dropped phone numbers, switching to cell phone
- In late 2013, a database table was used to generate the 2014 Yellow Pages.

Obviously, there are differences between the two Phone Books. Doing a JOIN of database tables to figure out the differences between 2013, and 2014 should pose no problem.

Imagine merging the two phone books by hand to locate differences. Sounds insane, doesn't it? Notwithstanding, that is exactly what you are asking mysqld to do when you join two views. Remember, you are not joining real tables and there are no indexes to piggyback from.

Now, let's look back at the actual query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
viewA.TRID, 
viewA.hits,
viewA.department,
viewA.admin,
viewA.publisher,
viewA.employee,
viewA.logincount,
viewA.registrationdate,
viewA.firstlogin,
viewA.lastlogin,
viewA.`month`,
viewA.`year`,
viewA.businesscategory,
viewA.mail,
viewA.givenname,
viewA.sn,
viewA.departmentnumber,
viewA.sa_title,
viewA.title,
viewA.supemail,
viewA.regionname
FROM
viewA
LEFT JOIN viewB ON viewA.TRID = viewB.TRID
WHERE viewB.TRID IS NULL
```

You are using a virtual table (table with no indexes), viewA, joining it to another virtual table, viewB. The temp table being generated intermittently would be as large as viewA. Then, you running an internal sort on the large temp table to making it distinct.

## EPILOGUE

Given the internal mechanisms of evaluating JOINs, along the transient and indexless nature of the result set of a view, your original query (LEFT JOIN of two views) should be getting running times that are orders of magnitude. At the same time, the [**answer you got from StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22181150/491757) should perform well, given the same JOIN algorithm I just described.

I hope the gory details I just posted answers your question as to why.

Comment: I know you copied the ***"Views (including updatable views) are available in MySQL Server 5.6"*** from the official documentation but it sounds like views where introduced in 5.6 while they are available from 5.0 version.

Comment: I read that views do use the original indexes from the tables just not allow creation of a new index on its fields.
if I query the view on a Select * From view Where TRID=10 it will use the original index, no?

Answer (score 1):

`EXPLAIN EXTENDED [select query]` and then `SHOW WARNINGS` will show the rewritten form of the view.  From here, it is easier to analyze performance characteristics.

Sight checking queries is generally not easy to optimize.

Comment: I understand both of these tactics but does that answer the question?

Comment: It may :)  To paraphrase: any answer is speculation without this information.

Answer (score -2):

The answer has to do with the method of performing each of these operations.

Since views are inherently unindexed, JOIN operations using fields from views will take longer than JOIN operations using tables since the scan cannot use an index.

In this case, the lookup also limits the number of records that have to be returned in processing- it only pulls records from one view that don't exist in the other. The JOIN pulls all records and then checks to see if records exist in both.

Comment: Does this mean MySQL is not able to use indexes on the underlying table when querying a view?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, it doesn't.  This answer is incorrect in that regard.  If the `MERGE` algorithm can be used to process the view, the indexes on the underlying tables can and will be used.  Only if the view definition explicitly uses the `TEMPTABLE` algorithm or the view contains functionality that implicitly requires a temporary table, then the view results will be materialized into a temp table.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html