# How does ORDER BY FIELD() in MySQL work internally

Tags: mysql, order-by, fields

I understand how `ORDER BY` clause works and how the `FIELD()` function works. 
What i want to understand is how the both of them work together to sort. 
How are the rows retrieved and how is the sort order derived

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | stan    |
|  2 | kyle    |
|  3 | kenny   |
|  4 | cartman |
+----+---------+ 

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (3,2,1,4) ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)
```

The query above will result in

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  3 | kenny   |
|  2 | kyle    |
|  1 | stan    |
|  4 | cartman |
+----+---------+
```

something similar to saying ORDER BY 3, 2, 1, 4

QUESTIONS

- How does this work internally?
- How does MySQL get the rows, and calculate the sort order ?
- How does MySQL know it has to sort by the id column ?

Comment: try this variation of your query: `SELECT *, FIELD(id,3,2,1,4) AS f FROM mytable WHERE id IN (3,2,1,4);` Then add `ORDER BY f` or `ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)` and try again.

Comment: who on their right mind would put Cartman at the bottom of a list? He will be so pissed off! Better watch your self, don't you end up like Scott Tenorman

Answer (score 106, accepted):

For the record

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1,4);
```

should work as well because you do not have to order the list in the `WHERE` clause

As for how it works,

- [**FIELD()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) is a function that returns the index position of a comma-delimited list if the value you are searching for exists.

  - IF id = 1, then [**FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns 3 (position where 1 is in the list)
  - IF id = 2, then [**FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns 2 (position where 2 is in the list)
  - IF id = 3, then [**FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns 1 (position where 3 is in the list)
  - IF id = 4, then [**FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns 4 (position where 4 is in the list)
  - IF id = anything else, then [**FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns 0 (not in the list)
- The `ORDER BY` values are evaluated by what [**FIELD()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns

You can create all sorts of fancy orders

For example, using the [**IF()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY IF(FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)=0,1,0),FIELD(id,3,2,1,4);
```

This will cause the first 4 ids to appear at the top of the list, Otherwise, it appears at the bottom. Why?

In the `ORDER BY`, you either get 0 or 1.

- If the first column is 0, make any of the first 4 ids appear
- If the first column is 1, make it appear afterwards

Let's flip it with DESC in the first column

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY IF(FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)=0,1,0) DESC,FIELD(id,3,2,1,4);
```

In the `ORDER BY`, you still either get 0 or 1.

- If the first column is 1, make anything but the first 4 ids appear.
- If the first column is 0, make the first 4 ids appear in the original order

## YOUR ACTUAL QUESTION

If you seriously want internals on this, goto [pages 189 and 192 of the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577)

[image: MySQL Internals]

for a real deep dive.

In essence, there is a C++ class called `ORDER *order` (The `ORDER BY` expression tree). In `JOIN::prepare`, `*order` is used in a function called `setup_order()`. **Why in the middle of the `JOIN` class?** ***Every query, even a query against a single table is always processed as a JOIN (See my post [Is there an execution difference between a JOIN condition and a WHERE condition?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36391/is-there-an-execution-difference-between-a-join-condition-and-a-where-condition/36409#36409))***

The source code for all this is `sql/sql_select.cc`

Evidently, the `ORDER BY` tree is going to hold the evaluation of `FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)`. Thus, the numbers 0,1,2,3,4 are the values being sorted while carrying a reference to the row involved.

Comment: have you posted any answer that addresses the performance tuning when using `order by filed()` as it triggers the `Using temporary; Using filesort`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - Virtually any function and some operators are not [_sargable_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) . Hence the index cannot be used.to avoid the sort.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will be too far from actual code so not low level enough from what you wanted:

When MySQL cannot use index to retrieve data in sorted order, it creates a temporary table/resultset with all selected columns and some additional data - one of those is some kind of a column for storing the results of ORDER BY expression value for each row - then it sends this tmp table to a "filesort" rutine with info which column to sort by. After that the rows are in sorted order so it can pick them one by one and return selected columns.