# mysql query - how to delete duplicates based on highest int?

Tags: mysql, delete

I'm running a reverse auction website and I need to delete the duplicate bids and keep only the highest amount . lastPriceBid_rounded is the "amount". The duplicate is defined by the userId.

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| lastPriceBid         | varchar(125) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| dateBidded           | varchar(125) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| owner                | varchar(65)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| status               | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0                 |                   |
| userId               | varchar(125) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| siteId               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| lastPriceBid_rounded | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| from_nickname        | varchar(125) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| time_updated         | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update         |
|                                                                        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

So far I've tried

```
DELETE n1 
FROM offers n1, offers n2 
WHERE n1.lastPriceBid_rounded < n2.lastPriceBid_rounded 
AND n1.userId = n2.userId;
```

but it doesn't seem to work well. I still have some duplicates (I see that when I use `SELECT DISTINCT`).

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the DELETE Query not work ?

Whenever a table is used against itself in a query other than `SELECT`, rows tend to disappear during the optimization phase. I wrote about that back on Feb 22, 2011 : [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384)

> What can you do then ?

Create a new offers table to see what the table would look like if the DELETE were actually done:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS offers_after_delete;
CREATE TABLE offers_after_delete LIKE offers;
INSERT INTO offers_after_delete
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT userId,site,MAX(lastPriceBid_rounded) highest_amount
FROM offers GROUP BY userId,site) A
INNER JOIN offers B USING (userId,site);
```

Please note that I based the delete operation on a distinct user per unique site. Now, browse through `offers_after_delete`. If the table looks correct to you, then delete like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS offers_after_delete;
CREATE TABLE offers_after_delete LIKE offers;
INSERT INTO offers_after_delete
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT userId,site,MAX(lastPriceBid_rounded) highest_amount
FROM offers GROUP BY userId,site) A
INNER JOIN offers B USING (userId,site);
ALTER TABLE offers RENAME offers_old;
ALTER TABLE offers_after_delete RENAME offers;
DROP TABLE offers_old;
```

Please rehearse this on a DB Staging Server.

Give it a Try !!!