# Delete from table where multiple fields match select subquery from other table

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, delete

I want to delete an entry in a table where multiple fields match the results of another select subquery which takes data from another table.

This is what I have so far, though it doesn't work:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE table1.id IN
   (SELECT id
   FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b
   ON a.field1 = b.field1
   AND a.field2 = b.field2
   AND a.field3 = b.field3
   AND b.id = ?
   )
```

Comment: How it doesn't work? Is it working but slow? It is not deleting what you want? Is it throwing error?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the `DELETE JOIN` would be preferable

```
DELETE A.* FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 b
ON  A.id = B.id
AND a.field1 = b.field1
AND a.field2 = b.field2
AND a.field3 = b.field3
AND b.id = ?;
```

I wrote about why `DELETE` with `WHERE` involving a subquery is sort of unhealthy to deal with in a past post of mine back on `Feb 22, 2011`: [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384)

Even though there have been great strides in improving the Query Optimizer, evaluation of subqueries could make keys unavailable for key comparisons downstream.

## ALTERNATIVE

Try gathering the keys you know need to be deleted and do the `DELETE JOIN` with it:

```
CREATE TABLE DeleteIDs SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE 1=2;
INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT A.id FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 b
    ON  A.id = B.id
    AND a.field1 = b.field1
    AND a.field2 = b.field2
    AND a.field3 = b.field3
    AND b.id = ?
;
ALTER TABLE DeleteIDs ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
DELETE B.* FROM DeleteIDs A INNER JOIN table1 B;
DROP TABLE DeleteIDs;
```

## SUGGESTION

Maybe an index would help

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX id123 (id,field1,field2,field3);
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD INDEX id123 (id,field1,field2,field3);
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Why do you write `DELETE A.* FROM ....` instead of `DELETE A FROM ....`? Isn't the `*` needlessly redundant?

Comment: @Pacerier that's how I learned it 20 years doing Microsoft Access development. MySQL accepts it. So, it's just an old habit.

Comment: However it's somewhat wrong since it seems to suggest that you can do a `delete a.Column2` when really it deletes the entire row.

Comment: @Pacerier If it's in the SQL standard, - by definition - it is not wrong ;)