# Use "NOT IN" in the same table, Mysql

Tags: mysql, delete

I have a table like that:

```
table1
    +----+------+--------------+
    | id | name | phone_number |
    +----+------+--------------+
    | 1  |  A   | 111111111111 |
    +----+------+--------------+
    | 2  |  B   | 222222222222 |
    +----+------+--------------+
    | 3  |  C   | 222222222222 |
    +----+------+--------------+
    | 4  |  D   | 111111111111 |                                        
    +----+------+--------------+
    | 5  |  E   | 222222222222 |
    +----+------+--------------+
```

I want to keep only 1 of the same phone number, don't care name. So, the table should be:

```
table1
    +----+------+--------------+
    | id | name | phone_number |
    +----+------+--------------+
    | 1  |  A   | 111111111111 |
    +----+------+--------------+
    | 2  |  C   | 222222222222 |
    +----+------+--------------+
```

I tried many ways, many hrs to delete or select but doesn't work, I did use code to resolve this, but I will appreciate for any explanation, thank you.

```
DELETE FROM table1 
where id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1 group by phone)
```

always said: You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
where id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1 group by phone)
```

always return an empty result.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(id),MIN(name),phone_number FROM t GROUP BY phone_number`

Comment: are you trying to keep only rows with distinct phone numbers and delete the rest?

Answer (score 4):

Given this sample data:

```
root@localhost:playground > select * from t;
+------+------+--------------+
| id   | name | phone_number |
+------+------+--------------+
|    1 | A    | 111111111111 |
|    2 | B    | 222222222222 |
|    3 | C    | 222222222222 |
|    4 | D    | 111111111111 |
|    5 | E    | 222222222222 |
+------+------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

first you determine which rows you want to keep.

```
root@localhost:playground > select min(id), min(name), phone_number from t group by phone_number;
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| min(id) | min(name) | phone_number |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 | A         | 111111111111 |
|       2 | B         | 222222222222 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

With this query you can check which rows will be deleted:

```
root@localhost:playground > select * from t left join (select min(id) id, min(name) name, phone_number from t group by phone_number) a on a.id = t.id and a.name = t.name and a.phone_number = t.phone_number;
+------+------+--------------+------+------+--------------+
| id   | name | phone_number | id   | name | phone_number |
+------+------+--------------+------+------+--------------+
|    1 | A    | 111111111111 |    1 | A    | 111111111111 |
|    2 | B    | 222222222222 |    2 | B    | 222222222222 |
|    3 | C    | 222222222222 | NULL | NULL | NULL         |
|    4 | D    | 111111111111 | NULL | NULL | NULL         |
|    5 | E    | 222222222222 | NULL | NULL | NULL         |
+------+------+--------------+------+------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `delete` query:

```
root@localhost:playground > delete t.* from t left join (select min(id) id, min(name) name, phone_number from t group by phone_number) a on a.id = t.id and a.name = t.name and a.phone_number = t.phone_number where a.phone_number is null;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > select * from t;
+------+------+--------------+
| id   | name | phone_number |
+------+------+--------------+
|    1 | A    | 111111111111 |
|    2 | B    | 222222222222 |
+------+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another feasible approach would be this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_tmp LIKE t;

INSERT INTO t_tmp 
SELECT MIN(id), MIN(name), phone_number
FROM t
GROUP BY phone_number;

RENAME TABLE t TO t_backup, t_tmp TO t;
```

Comment: Why not CREATE TABLE.. AS SELECT...

Comment: @Mihai `CREATE TABLE AS` creates a table just with same datatypes, nothing else. `CREATE TABLE LIKE` creates a table including primary key and foreign keys and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using `group by`, if you don't care about other fields' values:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 LIKE t;
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t GROUP BY phone_number;
RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t1 TO t;
DROP TABLE t_old;
```

If the table `t` is huge, you may want to create it without indexes and after populating the data, you create the indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT * FROM t GROUP BY phone_number;
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD INDEX ...
RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t1 TO t;
DROP TABLE t_old;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, there is very important reason why

```
DELETE FROM table1 
where id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1 group by phone);
```

does not work.

MySQL processes subqueries in such a way that rows can sometimes disappear during its optimization and execution. This is not harmful to `SELECT` queries using subqueries in its `WHERE` clause. This does affect `DELETE` and `UPDATE` queries with such a `WHERE` clause. In that instance, it is much better to decompose the query into separate steps.

I wrote about this over the years

- `Feb 22, 2011` : [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384)
- `Jan 23, 2013` : [Problem with nested UPDATE queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/problem-with-nested-update-queries/33414#33414)
- `Jun 04, 2013` : [Delete from table where multiple fields match select subquery from other table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43803/delete-from-table-where-multiple-fields-match-select-subquery-from-other-table/43805#43805)
- `Jul 11, 2014` : [Slow DELETE in MySQL with a subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71227/slow-delete-in-mysql-with-a-subquery/71263#71263)