# How this can return more than 1 result?

Tags: mysql

How this query can return more than 1 row?

```
SELECT username FROM phpbb_users WHERE user_id = (SELECT (FLOOR(RAND() * (5050 - 50 + 1)) + 50));
```

Table meta:

```
CREATE TABLE `phpbb_users` (
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `user_permissions` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_perm_from` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_regdate` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username_clean` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_password` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_passchg` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_pass_convert` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email_hash` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_birthday` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_lastvisit` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_lastmark` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_lastpost_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_lastpage` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_last_confirm_key` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_last_search` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_warnings` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_last_warning` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_login_attempts` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_inactive_reason` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_inactive_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_posts` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_lang` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_timezone` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `user_dst` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_dateformat` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'd M Y H:i',
  `user_style` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_rank` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_colour` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_new_privmsg` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_unread_privmsg` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_last_privmsg` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_message_rules` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_full_folder` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-3',
  `user_emailtime` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_topic_show_days` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_topic_sortby_type` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 't',
  `user_topic_sortby_dir` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'd',
  `user_post_show_days` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_post_sortby_type` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 't',
  `user_post_sortby_dir` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
  `user_notify` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_notify_pm` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_notify_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_allow_pm` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_allow_viewonline` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_allow_viewemail` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_allow_massemail` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_options` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '230271',
  `user_avatar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_avatar_type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_avatar_width` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_avatar_height` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_sig` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_sig_bbcode_uid` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_sig_bbcode_bitfield` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_from` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_icq` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_aim` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_yim` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_msnm` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_jabber` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_website` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_occ` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_interests` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_actkey` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_newpasswd` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_form_salt` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_new` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_reminded` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_reminded_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_clean` (`username_clean`),
  KEY `user_birthday` (`user_birthday`),
  KEY `user_email_hash` (`user_email_hash`),
  KEY `user_type` (`user_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5056 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: If you're always expecting exactly one row (and never zero rows), be careful - the random number could land on the id for a user who has been deleted (or an increment value that was never assigned due to a rollback etc.). You will also miss any users that have been added since you last hard-coded the upper bound of your random number calculation.

Answer (score 11):

The reason is that the `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE user_id = (SELECT (FLOOR(RAND() * (5050 - 50 + 1)) + 50))
```

is evaluated once per row. So, for every row, a new call to `RAND()` is made and thus the query can return 0, 1, 2, 3 or more rows. There is a (albeit very small) chance that the query will return all rows of the table!

A similar problem with a `DELETE` statement, where the call to `RAND()` was in the `ORDER BY` clause: [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/12602#12602)

---

If you want the query to never return more than 1 row, you can evaluate the random number before the query, so the `RAND()` is called once:

```
SET @random_number = FLOOR(RAND() * (5050 - 50 + 1)) + 50 ;
SELECT username FROM phpbb_users WHERE user_id = @random_number ;
```

As @a1ex07 mentioned, you could also use a derived table:

```
SELECT u.username 
FROM
    (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (5050 - 50 + 1)) + 50 AS random_number) AS r
  JOIN 
    phpbb_users AS u
      ON u.user_id = r.random_number ;
```

---

As a **warning** though, I can't find any documentation for this behaviour so it's quite possible that it may change in future versions (only tested in 5.1 and 5.5 versions.)  The various optimizer enhancements in versions 5.6, 5.7 and MariaDB (5.1, 5.3+) may have already altered this behaviour.

Comment: I wonder if that is stated anywhere in documentation ?  You are 100% right , `explain` shows full scan for such query (contrary to `const primary 1 row` if I change subquery to constant value) . However, I'm surprised that if the query is rewritten to `JOIN` syntax (e.g. `... JOIN (SELECT FLOOR.... as rnd)b ON (b.rnd = a.user_id))` it evaluates only once and never return more than 1 row (`explain` confirms that no full scan involved). Even in case of `LEFT JOIN` `FLOOR(RAND)` seems to be evaluated only once.

Comment: @a1ex07 I don't know if it's in the documentation anywhere. And it's possible that the behaviour may not stay consistent with future upgrades (I did not test in MariaDB or in 5.6 or in 5.7). I think I should add a note.