# Make another column in a table equal to the primary key column

Tags: mysql, update

In my notes table (MySQL database) I have id as the primary key. I want the column `originalid` to be the value of the primary key. Here is the query I run after creating a record which I thought would work.

```
UPDATE notes SET originalid = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM notes) where id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM notes);
```

But I get the error

> You can't specify target table 'notes' for update in FROM clause

Any advice or solutions on how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained the error message in an earlier post 4.5 years ago ([Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384))

## SUGGESITON : Do it as two queries

```
SELECT id INTO @maxid FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
UPDATE notes SET originalid = @maxid where id = @maxid;
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxid FROM notes;
UPDATE notes SET originalid = @maxid where id = @maxid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just run:

`UPDATE notes SET originalid = id;`

Make sure your data types match (e.g. if `id` is `INT(11)`, `originalid` should also be `INT(11)`.

Comment: That would overwrite `original_id` where the primary key `id` on every row. The question shows that Schwarz only wants this to occur on the last row.

Comment: Okay.  There was no indication in his question as to why he was applying the `MAX()` in his SQL statement.  It just appeared that he was overcomplicating the query based on the wording of his question.

Answer (score 0):

MAX(id) can have different values in case you have concurrent users. Even in a transaction you can read different values in a READ-COMMITTED and READ-UNCOMMITTED isolation level.

Just write exactly what you described with limiting the update to a reasonable subset of rows. For example running this after your insert will **always set the correct values**.

```
UPDATE notes SET originalid = id WHERE originalid IS NULL;
```

This will only update originalid which haven't yet been set and with the correct value.

Also please note that you can have the last insert id by the function LAST_INSERT_ID function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

So this would also work (and you don't need an index on originalid to be effective)

```
UPDATE notes SET originalid = id WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```