# Is it possible to switch queries based on an input in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, condition, interval

Is there a way to switch queries based on values? Let's say I have the below query:

```
select pdate as 'Payment Date', ROUND(@sum_amount := @sum_amount + `amount`) AS 'Total Amount' from
(
select @sum_amount := 0, date(issue_date) pdate, sum(amount) amount from payments group by YEAR(date(issue_date))
) inner_tbl
```

I want to change query interval (yearly, monthly, daily) based on user input. Something like below:

```
SELECT CASE input WHEN 1 THEN **RUN YEARLY QUERY**
     WHEN 2 THEN **RUN MONTHLY QUERY** ELSE **RUN DAILY QUERY** END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with basic logical operations (IF, THEN, ELSE etc)

In this situation you'd want to get the INPUT value and check it against your conditions (pseudocode):

```
IF INPUT = 'YEARLY' THEN
BEGIN
INSERT QUERY HERE
END
END IF

IF INPUT = 'MONTHLY' THEN
BEGIN
INSERT QUERY HERE
END
END IF
```

For more information on this check the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: `IF` statements must be done either in a Stored Procedure or with application code.  `IF` does not work as a standalone SQL statement.